# What is an efficient expression for a gradually reducing gradient or dichotomy between two previous distinct categories?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a way to express the gradual reduction in a division between two groups similar to the one used in this sentence:
"The dichotomy between reliable and false information has gradually eroded to the point where ..." (@Lambie)

This is meant to be a university-level essay but I am unable to determine such a word or expression to replace "gradual erosion of the barrier"

Comment: A dichotomy is not a quantity to decline. Maybe its extremes soften.

Comment: The dichotomy **between** A and B has gradually **eroded** to the point where//to erode.

Comment: When you edited your question, you took my suggestion and now want to change that? You could at least give me credit for suggesting erode.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth has picked a good word, but you need to change a couple of other words: *The **distinction** between reliable and false information has gradually **become** blurred, to the point where ...* (*Blurred* is a past participle adjective here.)

Answer (score 2):

There has been **a blurring of the distinction between** the two once (considered) disjoint categories.

> *blur* [verb] ...
>
> ...   to make the difference between two things less clear, or to make it difficult to see the exact truth about
> something:
>
> - *This film blurs the line/distinction/boundary between reality and fantasy.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blur)]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use "boundaries have become compromised" or ""boundaries have collapsed".

Answer (score 1):

In scientific and technical contexts *blurring/blurred the distinction* is commonly used for such descriptions.

The OP may wish to retain their original sentence (with slight modification) and use either the verb *"vanish*" or the noun *"vanishing point*" instead of *"erode*" to make their point.

> The distinction between reliable and false information has gradually *vanished* to the point where...

> The distinction between reliable and false information has gradually reached *vanishing point* where...

Per *Collins*

> If you say that something has reached *vanishing point*, you mean it has become very small or unimportant.

*By 1973, this gap had narrowed almost to vanishing point.*

Answer (score -2):

**Morph** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morph)) Verb

1. (colloquial, transitive, intransitive, computer graphics) To change shape, from one form to another, through computer animation.
2. (science fiction, fantasy) To shapeshift.
3. (by extension) To undergo dramatic change in a seamless and barely noticeable fashion.

   - e.g. The friendly person morphed into a devilish politician.

I like this other word better but "**morph**" is a better fit to your situation.

**Transmogrify** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmogrify))

1. (transitive) To completely alter the form of.
2. (intransitive) To completely alter one's form.

e.g.

But 'Hamilton,' directed by Thomas Kail and starring Mr. Miranda, might just be about worth it—at least to anyone who wants proof that the American musical is not only surviving but also evolving in ways that should allow it to thrive and **transmogrify** in years to come.

2015 August 5, “Review: `Hamilton,' Young Rebels Changing History and Theater”, in The New York Times:

Comment: This downvote needs explanation.

Comment: The second downvote needs explanation.